# how to draw a path on canvas after a specific time delay?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-animation, android-canvas, skiasharp

I want to draw a path on canvas after a specific time delay, i have checked this link [Draw a Path as animation on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703666/draw-a-path-as-animation-on-canvas)
  but it does not explain the problem i am looking for.

i just want a delay before i draw a path.

```
private void OnPainSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
 {
      canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
      canvas.Clear();


      foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
      {
           //Delay before drawing a path, ex: 5 seconds
           canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postInvalidateDelayed` method on a `View`

In your example that would be

```
foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
  {
       //Delay before drawing a path, ex: 5 seconds
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
       canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
  }
```

**EDIT**

You can just use `Handler` to give a delay in each iteration, in Kotlin it's done like this

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
}, 5000)
```

**EDIT 2**

You can try this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Action action = () => 
{
   canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
};

handler.postDelayed(action, 5000);
```

Comment: this did not work, it is drawing everything instantly.

Comment: I edited the answer, can you try the new solution ?

Comment: yes i did that, i am calling `invalidate` on button press and inside the above `OnPaintSurface` method `foreach` loop  i am calling this  `canvasView.PostInvalidateDelayed(2000);
                    canvas.DrawPath(path.Item2, paint);`

Comment: tried it crashed the app `Handler h = new Handler();
                    Action myAction = () =>
                    {
                        canvas.DrawPath(path.Item2, paint);
                    };

                    h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1000);`

Comment: What the crash says ?

Comment: i will check again tomorrow and revert :)

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Still waiting for the crash log