# Repeat pulse Animation

Tags: android, loops, animation

I'm trying to create a Infinite pulsing effect in a ImageView.
But how is it possible to keep the offset?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"/>
<scale
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="700"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This will make your (Image)View pulsate up to 1.2 its size and back, repeatedly.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);

ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
                    iv,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.2f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.2f));
scaleDown.setDuration(310);

scaleDown.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
scaleDown.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

scaleDown.start();
```

Comment: To make this movement more natural I remommend adding interpolator like this one:  scaleDown.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());

Comment: How do you pause in between animations?

Comment: I tried this but this can cause it to have jagged edges, it looks a lot cleaner to use an animated vector drawable instead.

Comment: can i make this animation in xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `startOffset` values for each animations in your set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create infinite animation, the best way would be to create custom View and in onDraw create your animation. For example: [How to animate a path on canvas - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android)

Actually you can do animation with SurfaceView too.