# How to path morph using the Path class?

Tags: android, canvas

I currently have two vector paths in a `VectorDrawable` and I am morphing one to another using `AnimatedVectorDrawable`:

First path:

```
M 1890.8582,2192.6484 L 505.06434,1392.5588 C 169.4833,2023.6601 168.2137,2777.0708 503.79469,3408.1721 L 1891.1961,2607.1555 C 1836.8977,2474.0145 1836.5598,2325.7894 1890.8582,2192.6484 Z
```

and my second path:

```
M 2300,200 L 200,200 C 200,1666.6667 200,3133.3333 200,4600 L 2300,4600 C 2300,3133.3333 2300,1666.6667 2300,200 Z
```

The catch is that the second path is dependent on the size of the screen, so some math has to go into those figures and I have to set them dynamically.

As it stands, it seems there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. So I have decided to use the `Path` class and draw it on a `Canvas`. The problem is that doesn't seem to be to be a way to morph paths when drawing with `Path`.

So my question is, is there some way to morph paths that have been set dynamically?

I have been looking at the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android) question and if all else fails, I'm going to take their suggestion and move the points of the path as the animation draws frame-by-frame on a `Canvas`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: see `PathParser#interpolatePathDataNode` method, this is the place where morphing is done

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of the existence of this class. So is the idea to have `onDraw` loop over each iteration of the node? Although this is already plenty helpful, are there any examples of this in use? Thanks

Comment: how are you creating your `Path` object based on `"M 2300,200 L 2..."` string?

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I'm saying that I'm going to switch from using the svg path string to using the `Path` class, but there doesn't seem to be a way to morph paths in the `Path` class.