# How to draw path with animation?

Tags: android, animation, path, duration

```
green_paintbrush_stroke = new Paint();
green_paintbrush_stroke.setColor(Color.GREEN);
green_paintbrush_stroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
green_paintbrush_stroke.setStrokeWidth(10);

tik = new Path();
tik.moveTo(25,50);
tik.lineTo(50,100);
tik.moveTo(50,100);
tik.lineTo(100,-1);
```

I want to draw mypath with animation duration. Can you help me please?

Comment: *drawing path* has nothing to do with animation. You can draw one path within one frame (of the animation), another path within another frame, etc.

Comment: I think someone already answered this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android

Comment: this solution didn't work for me :S

Comment: Can we delay onDraw method?

Comment: You did not say for what purpose but you can look into vector drawable animations. That lets you define lines but also expose them during animation sequence giving the feel they are being drawn slowly