# Gesture automatically draws itself

Tags: android, draw, gesture

I've seen it on Dolphin Browser. There're some gestures that're already created by default. They will redraw themselves so that users know where to begin drawing. I've noticed that in Gesture object, there's a method named toPath(). But I have no clue how to use it and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Can somebody tell me how to do it? Thanks. You can take a look at the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest to take a look at **GestureBuilder** app from SDK samples. It has exactly that is shown in your question (small gesture thumbnails).

I've slightly extended that example to make usage of `Gesture` APIs more clear:

Add the following code into **GestureBuilderActivity** from **GeatureBuilder** sample:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowGestureActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(ShowGestureActivity.GESTURE_NAME_EXTRA, ((NamedGesture)v.getTag()).name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It will launch new test activity **ShowGestureActivity**:

```
public class ShowGestureActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String GESTURE_NAME_EXTRA = "gesture_extra";
    private Gesture mGesture = null;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;
    private MyPathView mMyPathView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.show_gesture);

        final ArrayList<Gesture> gestures = GestureBuilderActivity.getStore()
                .getGestures(getIntent().getStringExtra(GESTURE_NAME_EXTRA));

        if (gestures.size() == 1) {
            mGesture = gestures.get(0);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No gesture available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mMyPathView = (MyPathView) findViewById(R.id.myPathView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_gesture_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final int id = item.getItemId();

        if (mGesture == null) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_show_gesture_bmp:
                final Bitmap gestureBmp = mGesture.toBitmap(mContainer.getWidth(), mContainer.getHeight(),
                        getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gesture_thumbnail_inset), Color.YELLOW);

                mMyPathView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), gestureBmp));
                return true;

            case R.id.action_show_gesture_path:
                mMyPathView.setPath(mGesture.toPath(mContainer.getWidth(), mContainer.getHeight(),
                        getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gesture_thumbnail_inset), 10));
                mMyPathView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mContainer.setBackground(null);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In `onOptionsItemSelected` you can see usage of both `Gesture` methods available for drawing. Seems `toBitmap` is quite clear (**GesturesBuilder** app itself uses that method for gestures thumbnails display in the list).
Regarding `toPath`: it provides you with the path which corresponds to the `Gesture`. After that you can use that path for drawing as you want. `MyPathView` from test activity above provides easiest way of doing so:

```
public class MyPathView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath = null;

    public MyPathView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public MyPathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyPathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.paint_width));
    }

    public void setPath(final Path path) {
        mPath = path;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mPath != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

And xml is (just to make example easy to compile):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <com.sandrstar.testapp.test.MyPathView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myPathView"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

If you want to apply some kind of animation to gesture drawing, you need to get path, create custom view as described above and apply some animation method, e.g. like one described here [Draw path on canvas with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037709/how-to-draw-a-path-on-an-android-canvas-with-animation)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... Great! I got the idea now. Before reading your answer, I used [AnimatedPathView](https://github.com/matthewrkula/AnimatedPathView) to achieve this animation. But supposing I have a lot of different gestures, how can I control every single animation for every gesture following the instruction from the link you gave me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by control every single animation? That AnimatedPathView + Animator provides enough control of animation. Also, view from link in my answer can be easily extended in order to have more control over animation (e.g. start-stop).

Comment: I mean I want to use your way rather than a library. Please forget the AnimatedPathView, I just happened to mention it. Right now I'm working on the link you gave me. Thanks :)

Comment: Just consider usage of Animator, because it might give your activity/fragment more control over that animation and require less code than provide all animation logic inside custom view.