# Playing Gestures on Android

Tags: android, gestures

I have created gestures for my app in Gestures Builder. How do I ***play*** those gestures on emulator/device in my app. I have included the gesture file in my Raw resource.. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the gestures in your app from your resource and then write code to recognize it.

Follow this tutorial here https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/tag/gesture-builder/

Comment: thnx a lot..@Klitos. G.. Gesture recognition worked.. But how do I play a saved gesture on a screen in an app ?

Comment: When you say "play" you mean you want to draw your gesture on your screen animated? If you need this, then take a look on the second part of the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553687/gesture-automatically-draws-itself

Comment: thnx again @Klitos G. I want to ask my user to draw a particular gesture that I will first show to him on Screen 1. When the user draws a gesture, I want the Gesture API to compare 'user-drawn' gesture with only one gesture from the file vs. all gestures in file as it's happening right now.                             Step 1 : User is shown a gesture to be drawn(on Screen 2) on Screen 1.     Step 2 : User is asked to draw the same gesture.      Step 3 : Inputs from Step 2 to be compared with gesture (id).

Comment: I think you do not need any more code than the given, but as you now have the code and a scenario, please ask a new question on how to implement this scenario. Basically you need the steps you describe translated into views inside an Activity(or Fragment).