# Android draw circle path animation

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

I am trying to achieve an animated circular path to be drawn in 2 seconds in an ImageView in my application. Currently I have achieved to draw it but it just appears in my ImageView and I'd like to animate it using some kind of radial wiping in.

I can refer to this question asked based on an iOS application: [How do you achieve a "clock wipe"/ radial wipe effect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios)

I'd like to have my circular path animated the same way with a duration of 2 seconds. How do I achieve that?

Currently this is my code.

```
private void createBitMap() {
        Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  //creates bmp
        bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     //lets bmp to be mutable
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 //draw a canvas in defined bmp

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        // smooths
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2.5f);
        // opacity
        //p.setAlpha(0x80); //
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 45, paint);
        ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    }
```

I call this method simply like this: `createBitMap();`, and I'd like to continue doing that. This method only makes a drawn circle appear in my imageview so now I need to animate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adapt something like this answer:
[How to draw a path on an Android canvas with animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037709/how-to-draw-a-path-on-an-android-canvas-with-animation)

in the onDraw function, remember how much of an angle you have drawn currently and use canvas.drawArc to draw a slightly larger arc.